# What is the difference between `Lookup` and `StaticLookup`?

Tags: traits

The docs say that `StaticLookup` does not require "context" whereas `Lookup` does. What does this mean? Is there an example or a pallet where we can look at both `Lookup` and `StaticLookup` implementations to see how they differ?

```rust
/// Means of changing one type into another in a manner dependent on the source type.
pub trait Lookup {
    /// Type to lookup from.
    type Source;
    /// Type to lookup into.
    type Target;
    /// Attempt a lookup.
    fn lookup(&self, s: Self::Source) -> Result<Self::Target, LookupError>;
}

/// Means of changing one type into another in a manner dependent on the source type.
/// This variant is different to `Lookup` in that it doesn't (can cannot) require any
/// context.
pub trait StaticLookup {
    /// Type to lookup from.
    type Source: Codec + Clone + PartialEq + Debug + TypeInfo;
    /// Type to lookup into.
    type Target;
    /// Attempt a lookup.
    fn lookup(s: Self::Source) -> Result<Self::Target, LookupError>;
    /// Convert from Target back to Source.
    fn unlookup(t: Self::Target) -> Self::Source;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, this only difference is about the revert.

`Lookup`:

- `A -> B` ✓
- `B -> A`

`StaticLookup`:

- `A -> B` ✓
- `B -> A` ✓

For example, you define an account id conversion algorithm.

`AccountId32 -> AccountId20`, truncate the first 20 bytes.

This is not recoverable. You should use `Lookup` here.

Answer (score 1):

`Lookup::lookup` has a `self` parameter and `StaticLookup` does not.
So you can carry around some context in the `self` of the `Lookup` trait.

Otherwise inverting a value may not be defined for different contexts.
But yea, the implications in the doc are a bit weird.

Comment: Could you point to a non trivial implementation of `Lookup` ?

Comment: Imaging converting an EVM address to a Substrate `AccountId` but you want to take the Ethereum-ChainId into account. Could be part of the context. But i don't have good example code.